# Регулярное выражение, запрещающее все буквы русского алфавита на JS

Tags: регулярные-выражения, qregexp

Регулярное выражение, запрещающее все буквы русского алфавита.
`/^[А-Яа-я]*$/` - такой способ срабатывает вначале строки, а дальше не работает.

```
if (/^[А-Яа-я]*$/.test(input.value)) {
    input.style.border = '2px solid red';
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так?

Comment: Думаю стоит более подробно описать реализацию вашего запрета с написанием примера кода

Comment: Уберите символы `^` и `$`

Comment: а зачем в регулярке вы написали квалификаторы начала и конца строки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как Вам уже написали -- у Вас лишние символы начала и конца строки, можно реализовать, например, так:

```js
const input = document.getElementById("id");
input.addEventListener('input', test);

function test() {
  if (/[А-Яа-я]/.test(input.value)) {
    input.style.border = '2px solid red';
  } else {
    input.style.border = '2px solid green';
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="id" type="text">
```